# How to know what type of exceptions Windows store app types could throw?

Tags: c#, exception, windows-store-apps

I am using this method: [DatagramSocket.BindEndpointAsync()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.sockets.datagramsocket.bindendpointasync.aspx)

How the frig am I to know what type exceptions it could throw?? This [offical sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/DatagramSocket-sample-76a7d82b/sourcecode?fileId=57971&pathId=589460989) shows catching all exceptions like so:

```
        // Start listen operation. 
        try 
        { 
            await listener.BindServiceNameAsync(ServiceNameForListener.Text); 
            rootPage.NotifyUser("Listening", NotifyType.StatusMessage); 
        } 
        catch (Exception exception) 
        { 
            CoreApplication.Properties.Remove("listener"); 

            // If this is an unknown status it means that the error is fatal and retry will likely fail. 
            if (SocketError.GetStatus(exception.HResult) == SocketErrorStatus.Unknown) 
            { 
                throw; 
            } 

            rootPage.NotifyUser("Start listening failed with error: " + exception.Message, NotifyType.ErrorMessage); 
        }
```

But that seems terribly sloppy - surely there is a better way?

Comment: You don't. You have to rely on the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

C# does not require developer to mark each method with a list of exceptions that it can throw (Java has that requirement). That's why you have to rely on documentation or examine source code and figure it out.

Async/Await does not change anything in that case.

Comment: I know it doesn't - whats a developer to do when the documentation lacks the type exceptions that could occur??

Comment: I guess you are right in that it has nothing to do with the fact this happens to be awaitable - its just in the past the documentation - msdn and code - always included this information..

Comment: @user1896654 The documentation of .Net methods does, but you're talking about WinRT. Exceptions work differently there behind the scenes. But I agree that the documentation should be improved by including the possible exceptions.